# PyQt6: Как создать таблицу с флажками в одном из столбцов?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на PyQt6 реализовать таблицу из 4 столбцов и N строк, которая, в последнем столбце, содержит только флажки? Таблица имеет отображение в базе данных и последний столбец определяет значение (True/False) аналогичного столбца в таблице этой базы.

Требуется, чтобы при установке или снятии флажка, создавался запрос к БД на изменение значения в соответствующей ячейке таблицы из БД.

Рассматривал такой концепт:

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt


class MyTable(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        # Устанавливаем количество строк и столбцов в таблице
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(5)
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(3)

        # Создаем цикл для добавления чекбоксов в каждую ячейку таблицы
        for row in range(self.table_widget.rowCount()):
            for column in range(self.table_widget.columnCount()):
                checkbox_item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row))
                if column == 2:
                    checkbox_item.setFlags(Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled)
                    checkbox_item.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
                    checkbox_item.setText('')
                self.table_widget.setItem(row, column, checkbox_item)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        print(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Создание объекта приложения
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Создание окна
    window = MyTable()

    # Отобразить окно на экране
    window.resize(330, 200)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: Пример таблицы]

Не понятно:

1. Какое именно событие нужно перехватить, чтобы отловить установку или снятие флажка?
2. Как связать события конкретного флажка с конкретной строкой таблицы? Тут есть некоторые соображения, но как сделать правильно?

Возможно, это не самое подходящее решение. Тогда прошу подсказать другое, более правильное. Большого опыта на PyQt не имею.